# TNotebook or TPageControl

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-2006

I have an application using `TNotebook` to switch between different sub pages, that are shown.

Now I have to extend this code a little bit (namely add a page and change sizes).

I was told that `TNotebook` shouldn't be used anymore. In Delphi's help  I find "New applications should use TPageControl".

My question: Should I refactor the code to use `TPageControl` instead of `TNotebook`? What are the disadvandtages of TNotebook?

Comment: TNotebook has some misfeatures like lacking support with VCL Styles and Structure View. In Delphi 5 i prefered TNotebook for its simplicity, but recently making an applicaiton in XE2 i switched to TPageControl for overall smoother integration

Comment: @Arioch'The You should post as an answer

Comment: @TobyAllen I think there would be people with more facts than inexact vague impressions that i can offer

Comment: @Arioch'The I plan switching to XE?, so this will influence my decision.

Comment: But be warned that in XE2 TPageControl has bug with background color always-white ignoring the property

Comment: @Arioch'The That's not a bug. That is by design. The control adheres to the prevailing system theme. You'll find that for just about all system controls.

Comment: i do not have any special themes. And all other controls - TPanel, TGroupBox, TRadioGroup, TForm - have "silver gray" background. But TPanel does not. There was something specific in XE2 about it, i do not remember exactly. I just made it part of design :-)

Comment: No. It's the Vista+ theme.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if so, then there comes a need to revive TNotebook or to find a replacement of it. Because TPageControl then is no more a substitute for TNotebook due to different appearance.

Comment: @Arioch Hardly. All system controls behave that way. You'll find the color property has no effect. VCL styles allows you to use these controls with custom colors. And lots of bugs!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but i did not set any special style and Color property worked for other ocntrols...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage of `TPageControl`, in my opinion, is that it is a system native control, unlike `TNotebook`. When you use system native controls, the control is painted by the system, and so takes on the look and appearance that is native to the operating system that you use.

When the application is run on a new version of the OS, your control automatically gets the appearance that is native to that OS. What's more, the behaviour is system native. By that I mean the way the control responds to keyboard input and so on. That's less of an issue with `TPageControl` since the system does not provide that much default behaviour. But as a general rule the advice is sound.

When none of the system native controls meet your specific requirements, you may need to use a non-native control. And then you have to work to make sure that your control adapts to its surroundings. But when there is a system native control, unless there is a strong reason to avoid it, you should use it.

Comment: In my current application TNotebook is used without tabs, just to switch, wich controls are visible. So I think the comment of @Arioch'The regarding VCL styles does not apply (not sure about "Structure View")?
I am aware of the common considerations in this answer - but that I don't see any concrete disadvandtages (for now), so I think, I wont change the code (at the moment). Thanks.

Comment: Obviously the choice is yours what you use, but I don't think that there's much more to say on this than I already did. I guess you know that TPageControl can also be used in this "wizard" mode with no tabs showing. And when you do, your app will look like standard themed system dialogs. So it comes down to whether you want to use native look, or use your own app's personal look.

Answer (score 2):

Another disadvantage of TNotebook is that it excludes the form or frame on which it is placed from inheritance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think your answer should really have been a comment, but what new users can do at SO is very limited, until they have gained sufficient reputation points.  And you make a good point, so I'm upvoting your answer.